# Paths to images are messed up in Vagrant

Tags: media, virtual-machine

All the paths linking to modules, javascript, css are correct when I move a site locally and run in a vagrant environment. Yet, the image paths stored in the site come out wrong, so they are all borked.

The console in Chrome shows the paths to the images as skipping a folder. This is how the path looks: localhost/sites/default/files/img.jpg

This is how the path should look: localhost/sitename/sites/default/files/img.jpg

For some reason, Drupal in Vagrant looks for the sites folder in the localhost folder. I feel like something is wrong with the way apache is set up on my Vagrant installation. But I suppose it could be a number of things. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think I figured out that the solution to my problem involves updating the apache configuration for each site I run locally. My hosting service does this for me on the prod, but you can update it locally. Probably system admin 101 stuff: http://www.techmalaya.com/2008/06/09/apache-22-virtual-hosting/

Comment: Linked resource returns 404

Answer (score 0):

you should add your site name to the base url in .htaccess file and uncomment the base url code.

Comment: I think you add the base URL to the settings.php file. But that didn't help, as it's a configuration with apache.